# DxGrid both way databinding to Entity Framework entities

Tags: entity-framework-4, devexpress

I’m using EF 4.0. I’ve got fluent API mapping between my model and database. In one of small utility applications I want just to display my entities as a table, so I can add/edit/delete records from the WPF user interface using DevExpress Grid control. I followed their video http://tv.devexpress.com/#DXGridWPFBindEF4 and now I see my data in the grid, but I can’t edit it.

```
            control.gridUsers.ItemsSource = new LinqServerModeSource
                                            {
                                                ElementType = typeof (User),
                                                KeyExpression = "Login",
                                                QueryableSource = control._dbContext.Users
                                           };
```

Is there any way of making this binding working in both ways?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got response from DevExpress support team which helped me.

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q442601.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Not with the LinqServerModeSource as datasource because it is read-only. The "server mode"-datasources are intended to display large datasources. They implement a paging mechanism so not all of the data from the server is queried and transfered to the client but only the currently visible part.